# flutter jsonDecode failed in parsing data

Tags: json, flutter, dio

I'am tring to parse a String camed from dio.post method but json.decode(response.data) failed an gave me this error description [log] FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
{"test":"good"},this is not the real response but I use it tring to detect the failure cause ,and even with this short valid json string it failed ,but in the others requests it work correctly

I expect to get Map<String,dynamic> variable but it failed and I cant use dio response directly without decode it

Comment: You should display the actual string captured when it shows that error... typically, it's that you're unexpectedly getting some HTML or other text instead of your JSON.

Comment: I fix it by write json.decode(response.data.toString().subString(2));   I don't know why it actually solve the problem but it's work

Answer (score -1):

To add a reviver in the **json.decode(decodeSource,reviver)**

**The optional [reviver] function is called once for each object or list property that has been parsed during decoding. The key argument is either the integer list index for a list property, the string map key for object properties, or null for the final result.
The default [reviver] (when not provided) is the identity function.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).